# SQL Server - Selecting MAX record by another value

Tags: sql, sql-server, max, sql-order-by

I have a table with four columns: Note ID, Contact ID, Created By, and Created Date.  I want to run a query that will return the most recent CREATED BY (i.e. "John Smith") by CONTACT ID.  Contact ID, naturally, can appear multiple times in the table.

I obviously would normally run a `MAX()` statement by the Created Date column, but the problem is I need to have the Contact ID & Created By present in the returned data, but I can't group by both of those columns because I would then receive multiple rows per Contact ID/Created By Grouping.

In the example below, what I would like to see returned is: `1118653/Katy Combs`, as she has the most recent CreatedOn.

```
ContactID   Created By         Created Date
1118653     Katy Combs         2020-10-19 19:58:11.687
1118653     Danielle Scarrone   2020-10-15 18:07:01.630
```

Comment: This has been answered a hundred times, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/3800551/2527905

Answer (score 1):

The simple way, do `ORDER BY` to get the newest rows first. Use `TOP 1` to get only one row, the newest one.

```
select top 1 t.*
from tablename t
order by [Created Date] desc
```